# voltage gain and current gain in a common emitter

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, gain

How can I calculate the voltage gain and current gain of this circuit? The voltage gain is giving me -204.49, but with the oscilloscope gave me a gain of approximately 10 (positive). I do not understand where I was wrong.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume \$\beta = 200 \$ the voltage gain is: 
$$ A_v \approx - \frac{R_3}{\frac{R2 + r_\pi}{(\beta+1)}}\approx -8.7\; V/V$$

And you get the wrong result because you don't include R2 influence.

Transistor gain alone is \$ - gm*R_O = 47.6mS * 4.3K \Omega = - 204 \; V/V \$

But this is true only if the base is connected directly to the input source.

In your circuit we have \$R_2\$ in series with \$r_ \pi\$.

Hence, we have the voltage divider

$$\frac{r_\pi}{R2+r_\pi} = \frac{8.4k\Omega}{8.4k\Omega + 100k \Omega} = 0.07749 $$

So, the overall voltage gain is

$$Av = -204 * 0.07749 = - 15.8 \; V/V$$

Comment: And how I can calculate the current gain for this circuit?

Comment: It will depend on how you define the current gain. For me Ai = IR3/Isource